# Insert Stored Procedure with null parameters

Tags: sql, stored-procedures

I want to create an insert stored procedure with null parameters, if pass the value for that parameter then it has to insert or update in database

My stored procedure is:

```
Create proc [dbo].[SP_InsertOrUpdateCourseDetails]
    @CourseID int,
    @Tab1Title nvarchar(250) = null,
    @Tab1Description nvarchar(max) = null,
    @Tab2Title nvarchar(250) = null,
    @Tab2Description nvarchar(max) = null,
    @Tab3Title nvarchar(250) = null,
    @Tab3Description nvarchar(max) = null,
    @Tab4Title nvarchar(250) = null,
    @Tab4Description nvarchar(max) = null,
    @Syllabus nvarchar(max) = null
As
Begin

    If NOT EXISTS (Select * from CourseDetail Where CourseID=@CourseID )
    Begin
        Insert into CourseDetail(CourseID, Tab1Title, Tab1Description, 
                                 Tab2Title, Tab2Description,
                                 Tab3Title, Tab3Description, Tab4Title, Tab4Description,
                                 Syllabus)
        values (@CourseID, @Tab1Title, @Tab1Description, @Tab2Title, @Tab2Description,
                @Tab3Title, @Tab3Description, @Tab4Title, @Tab4Description, @Syllabus)

        IF @@ERROR = 0 AND @@ROWCOUNT =1
        Begin
            Select top 1 CourseID from CourseDetail Order by CourseDetailID Desc
        End
        Else 
        Begin
             Select 0
        End
    End
 Else
 Begin
     Update CourseDetail 
     SET
        Tab1Title = @Tab1Title,
        Tab1Description = @Tab1Description,
        Tab2Title = @Tab2Title,
        Tab2Description = @Tab2Description,
        Tab3Title = @Tab3Title,
        Tab3Description = @Tab3Description,
        Tab4Title = @Tab4Title,
        Tab4Description = @Tab4Description,
        Syllabus = @Syllabus
     Where 
        CourseID = @CourseID

     IF @@ERROR = 0 AND @@ROWCOUNT =1
     Begin
         Select top 1 CourseID from CourseDetail Order by CourseDetailID Desc
     End
     Else 
     Begin
         Select 0
     End
   End
 End
```

Comment: Use `'Null'` for varchar field.

Comment: What if you'll need to set `NULL` value for any column?

Comment: If i am not passing value from my C# code i dont want to insert or update null value

Comment: You should use the [OUTPUT](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177564.aspx) clause, to return the row you have just inserted/updated, rather getting the top 1 ordered by coursedetailID. Firstly your method won't work unless the update happens to update the latest course ID, and also has no issue with concurrency.

Comment: I've found in some combinations like JDBC and SQL server you have to put all the parameters that are potentially nullable at the end of the query for some reason

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `ISNULL` function passing in it SP's parameter as first parameter and default value in case of insert or actual column's value in case of update:

```
    Insert into CourseDetail(CourseID, Tab1Title, Tab1Description, 
                             Tab2Title, Tab2Description,
                             Tab3Title, Tab3Description, Tab4Title, Tab4Description,
                             Syllabus)
    values (@CourseID, ISNULL(@Tab1Title, 'default value'), ISNULL(@Tab1Description,'default value'), ...


 Update CourseDetail 
 SET
    Tab1Title = ISNULL(@Tab1Title, Tab1Title),
    Tab1Description = ISNULL(@Tab1Description, Tab1Description),
    ....
 Where 
    CourseID = @CourseID
```

But in this case you won't can to set NULL value explicitely even if you'll need